# Undefined counting as a variable -- messes up with my isObjEmpty() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to `post` an object only if it's not empty. However I have code which causes properties to become undefined -- and when that happens, the obj is not empty anymore and the `post` still happens.

```
userSearchData = {};

$('#addContactForm').keyup(function()
{

    var email = $(this).find('input[name="email"]').val();
    var username = $(this).find('input[name="username"]').val();
    var fullName = $(this).find('input[name="fullName"]').val();

    userSearchData.email = email.length >= 3 ? email : undefined;
    userSearchData.username = username.length >= 3 ? username : undefined;
    userSearchData.fullName = fullName.length >= 3 ? fullName : undefined;

    console.log(userSearchData);

    if ( !isEmpty(userSearchData) )
    {
        console.log("Is empty")
        $.post( '/post/addContact', { userSearchData: userSearchData }, function( data ) 
        {
            console.log( data );
        });
    }

});
```

It's a "search" form, so if a user types for example "Blabla" as the username, and then erases letters to make it "Bl", then the username variable gets undefined, so it's not being sent when doing the post (I console log the object on the server side and the undefined variables are not considered which is good).

- How can I make my variables completely removed, instead of undefined when their length is below 3?
- I could probably modify the `isEmpty` function to return false if all keys are undefined, would that be better to do that? If so, how would you do it?

  ```
  var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

  function isEmpty (obj)
  {
      // null and undefined are "empty"
      if (obj == null) return true;

      // Assume if it has a length property with a non-zero value
      // that that property is correct.
      if (obj.length > 0)    return false;
      if (obj.length === 0)  return true;

      // Otherwise, does it have any properties of its own?
      // Note that this doesn't handle
      // toString and valueOf enumeration bugs in IE < 9
      for (var key in obj) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```

Comment: Wait, the code you're showing says post if isEmpty(userSearchData) is true, but you're saying you want to post if userSearchData is not empty.

Comment: Is there any reason why your using expressions to define the object property, instead of using an `if` statement? Because you could bypass your issue by only defining `userSearchObject.email` `if (email.length >= 3) { ... }`

Comment: The thing is if the user erases letters, then that variable should be re-defined to `undefined` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @bingo -- right I showed wrong code here but I'm using !isEmpty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing seems rather pointless, you can just do this instead

```
$('#addContactForm').on('keyup', function() {
    var userSearchData = {}, self = this;

    $.each(['email', 'username', 'fullName'], function(_, el)  {
        var val = $(self).find('input[name="'+el+'"]').val();
        if ( val.length > 3 ) userSearchData[el] = val;
    });

    $.post( '/post/addContact', { userSearchData: userSearchData }, function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still using if ( !isEmpty(userSearchData) ) to only post if not empty, but I'm using your answer, thanks!

Comment: @DanyP - I did rewrite that as well, I just deleted it as it didn't seem neccessary, but here it is -> http://jsfiddle.net/VRMz7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Only add the properties to the object if the condition is met.

```
if ( username.length >=3 ) {
    userSearchData.username = username;
}

if ( username in userSearchData ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is if a user erases letters, let's say he types "aaaa", then erases to "aa", the variable is still there and being posted, but I only want to post it if it has more than 3 letters.

Comment: Why would you set the object properties *before* the user is done entering data?

Comment: It's a dynamic search function -- I want to start showing results when there are at least 3 characters entered. I'm querying MySQL with the fields if they have more than 3 chars.

Comment: Actually, your way works if I simply move var userSearchData = {}; inside the keyup function so it's always re-initialized. Taken From adeneo's answer, will check if his way is preferable too. Thanks

Comment: The answer posted by [adeneo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) is worth a second look.

Answer (score 0):

you can `delete` properties in JS, but the better fix is to just make sure your code posts when it should.

`if (obj === null || obj === undefined) return;`

or something might help you here.

Also, `for(key in obj)` is old-style "iterate over prototype as well", and highly discouraged, so you probably want this instead:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
if(keys.length === 0) ...
keys.forEach(function(key) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want do this?

```
if(!isEmpty(userSearchData)){
     $.post( '/post/addContact', { userSearchData: userSearchData }, function( data ) 
    {
        console.log( data );
    });
}
```